# SSE on x86, stack alignment and __m128i function args

Tags: visual-c++, x86, sse, memory-alignment

The SSE code I have got was written for x64, where the stack is aligned by 16. The optimised code paths have now been requested for 32-bit x86 (for MSVC/Windows and GCC/Linux). Getting this working on MSVC first.

Now apart from some inlines that took more than 3 `__m128` parameters which it refused to compile (fixed by making a const ref and hoping the compiler will optimize it out) everything seems to work as is.

```
//error C2719: 'd': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned
inline __m128i foo(__m128i a, __m128i b, __m128i c, __m128i d) {...}
```

However I was under the impression the stack is not 16byte aligned on x86 Windows. Yet some `__declspec(align(16))` arrays on the stack didn't even get a warning, and I am sure it must be pushing and popping the `__m128`s (I recall working out 12 registers were required on x64, and even then it moved some to the stack it didn't need for a bit and did its own thing anyway).

I even added some asserts on the array memory addresses (and turned off NDEBUG) and they all seem to pass.

```
__declspec(align(16)) uint32_t blocks[64];
assert(((uintptr_t)blocks) % 16 == 0);

__m128i a = ...;
__m128i b = ...;
__m128i c = ...;
__m128i d = ...;
__m128i e = ...;
__m128i f = ...;
__m128i g = ...;
//do other stuff, which surely means there is not enough registers on x86
```

Did I just get really lucky or is there some magic going on here to realign the stack? And is this portable? I am sure I recall having issues getting some D3DX stuff to align on x86 when I was doing D3D9 back with VS2008.

One thing I did get a bunch of warnings for however was the `__m128` -> `__m128&` conversions being non-standard. Is this really not supported on some compiler that does support SSE, and how is one meant to avoid it (e.g. inlines with output `__m128`'s, or more than 3 params)?

Also a quick look suggests somehow MS themselves break these rules (e.g. XMMatrixTransformation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixtransformation%28v=vs.85%29.aspx takes 6 SSE objects, the only difference I can see being there wrapped in structs)

```
XMMATRIX XMMatrixTransformation(
  [in]  XMVECTOR ScalingOrigin,
  [in]  XMVECTOR ScalingOrientationQuaternion,
  [in]  XMVECTOR Scaling,
  [in]  XMVECTOR RotationOrigin,
  [in]  XMVECTOR RotationQuaternion,
  [in]  XMVECTOR Translation
);
```

Comment: Most ABIs insert padding if needed to get the required alignment, so if the stack is only 8 byte aligned they will still do the right thing for data types that require 16 byte alignment. I expect MS does the same thing in WIN32 (it would make life pretty difficult if they didn't !).

Comment: It depends on the compiler version you use.  VS2012 certainly generates stack addresses that are aligned to 16, it uses SSE2 heavily it is own code generator.

Answer (score 1):

The variables on stack are aligned. As far as I recall, Visual C++ always properly overaligned stack variables.

The error that you see for the fourth parameter is that your Visual C++ is not able to pass overaligned type as a value parameter passed as a pointer on stack. The first three are passed via registers.

Use `__vectorcall` to pass more parameters via registers (six), and to pass the rest of the parameters by stack value (thus avoiding the error even for 7th parameter).

Use the latest Visual C++ which can pass overaligned types normally (starting in Visual C++ 2017). (There was [a bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/incorrect-code-gen-missing-error/831543) fixed relatively recently, but it was about passing non-trivially copyable overaligned types, xmm types are trivially copyable, so they are fine).

Better use both latest Visual C++ and `__vectorcall` :-)